# How to organize project with multiple Go modules and use Docker compose?

Tags: docker, go

I'm new to Go and am confused about how to structure a project with multiple modules of my own and use them with `docker compose`. The project is currently a single git repository containing two modules: an API and a processor for long-running work, each running in their own container. RabbitMQ is used as a work queue between the two and there's a MySQL database as well.

A simplified view of the project structure:

```
├── api
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── stuff.go
├── docker-compose.yml
├── go.work
└── processor
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── stuff.go
```

API Dockerfile (the processor one is identical except for "api" is "processor"):

```
FROM golang:1.20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . .
RUN go build -v -o /usr/local/bin/ ./...

CMD [ "api" ]
```

Simplified docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      ...

  processor:
    build:
      context: ./processor
      ...

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.11-management
    ...

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ...
```

I run this with `docker compose up --build` and it works fine. The problem is there's some duplicate code in both modules that belongs in a shared module, but I don't know how to do that while still being able to build and work locally.

From researching this I get the impression that my modules should be in their own repositories. If I do that, it seems like I'd need to create a "project" repository just for the `docker-compose.yml`, then another for the shared module. I'd then update the `docker-compose.yml` contexts to point to wherever I cloned the API and processor projects when working locally.

The problem is the shared module wouldn't have a `Dockerfile` or be a service in the `docker-compose.yml`. I assume Docker would `go get` the contents of the shared module when building, but I still want to be able to work on that code locally without having to commit and push it to origin first.

Comment: Have you considered building a single Docker image containing both Go programs? You'd move the Dockerfile to the repository root and then simply run it twice, with different commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start off ignoring Docker here.

Arrange your filesystem tree however you would for a normal Go application, however you'd plan to package and distribute it.  You should be able to do your development with normal `go test` and `go build` commands.  It sounds like you have multiple top-level commands surrounding a shared code base; putting them in a single repository makes sense, but remember that each top-level command needs its own directory.

If you have a setup like this and you want to run it in Docker, the important detail is that you need to pass the entire source tree as the build-context directory.  A Dockerfile for each application is fine, and there's an argument for putting it in the same directory as its top-level application.  But when you declare it in Compose you must tell it the project root directory is the build context.

I'd put the `docker-compose.yml` file in the project root, next to the `go.mod` file.  It might look like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./cmd/api/Dockerfile
    ports: ['8000:8000']
  processor: { ... }
  rabbitmq: { ... }
  mysql: { ... }
```

Your Dockerfiles look essentially like what you've already shown.  Since the build context is the project root, all `COPY` commands start relative to the project root; on the other hand, you pretty much need to copy in the entire source tree no matter which application is building.  For Go I would almost always use a multi-stage build to avoid including the toolchain in the final image.

```bash
# cmd/api/Dockerfile; but built with a context of the project root
FROM golang:1.20 AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . .
RUN go build -o api ./cmd/api

FROM ubuntu:22.04  # "alpine" or "not alpine" must match build stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/api /usr/local/bin/
CMD ["api"]
```